# adding python packages for use in spark in aws EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I've just started using AWS EMR as part of the testing -I've created a boot-strap file to install particular python packages using pip on my EMR instance. I understand this is something quite basic. 
the bash script contains

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
pip install typing --user
```

However, when I submit the python script as a step, I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "py-calculate.py", line
>   6, in 
>       from typing import Iterable ImportError: No module named typing End of LogType:stdout

From what it looks like, The typing package isn't being installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had guessed, the typing package isn't being installed. the method I used to is to modify the bash script to

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo pip install -U typing
```

For some reason, this works better.